# Progress Bar not updating in Python container on Kubernetes

Tags: python, docker, logging, kubernetes

I am trying to get a simple progress bar working in my Python container on Kubernetes. However, it doesn't output anything until the job is done and the progress bar reaches 100%. The same exact code works perfectly in a local Docker container. So what is it that Kubernetes has in place that prevents me from seeing the progress bar updating in real time in its logs?

Progress bar code:

```
import sys
import time


class Color:
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'


ERASE_LINE = '\x1b[2K\r'


def percentage(current, total):
    percent = 100 * float(current) / float(total)
    return percent


class ProgressBar:

    def __init__(self, total):
        self._total = total
        self._current = 0
        self.print()

    def update(self):
        self._current += 1
        self.print()

    def print(self):
        percent = percentage(self._current, self._total)
        sys.stdout.write("\r")
        sys.stdout.write(Color.BOLD + "[%-50s] %d%%" % ('=' * int(percent / 2), percent) + Color.ENDC)
        sys.stdout.flush()


if __name__=="__main__":
    print("Ready to run soon...")
    time.sleep(10)
    print("Running!")
    pbar = ProgressBar(255)
    for i in range(255):
        time.sleep(0.03)
        pbar.update()
```

Comment: From where are you observing the output, a local/remote terminal session? Is it a local minikube?

Comment: Through a remote terminal session. I SSH into the k8s cluster and then run `logs -f` on the pod.

Comment: Ahh, that would be an issue. The logs tailing will wait for a `\n` before printing a line - and your script is rewriting the same line over and over as far as I can see. I guess the termination of the script or container sends an EOF or just flushes the buffer and adds a `\n`

Comment: That makes sense, I didn't think of it. Thanks for the insight. Would you have any ideas on how I could work around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When logging, rather than displaying things in a TTY to a human, you generally need to log in complete lines ending in `\n`. Rather than a progress bar, I would usually recommend something like printing out `10%...\n20%...\n etc`. Up to you how often you print the current state.

**Update:**

You can update your script to detect if the terminal is TTY, and change the behaviour accordingly

Use this:

```py
import os, sys
if os.isatty(sys.stdout.fileno()):
```

Comment: +1, and I added some info to this reply. You can use `os.isatty(sys.stdout.fileno())` to detect if stdout is a TTY terminal.